# counting mysql values

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with two fields, TAG_ID and TAG_DESC

my primary is tag_id.

I'm looking for a query that will display each TAG_DESC and the amount of times it occurs next to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT TAG_DESC as 'Description', 
         COUNT(TAG_DESC) as 'Occurances' 
    FROM table_name 
GROUP BY TAG_DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select TAG_DESC, count(*)
from MyTable
group by TAG_DESC
```